# What are the file types supported by MIP SDK?

Tags: microsoft-information-protection

Is there any complete list of file extensions supported by MIP SDK?

I was able to find a vague definition in
[MIP SDK - File handler concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/concept-handler-file-cpp#supported-file-types) and then something for [AIP unified labeling client](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Azure-RMSDocs/blob/master/Azure-RMSDocs/rms-client/clientv2-admin-guide-file-types.md) and [AIP classic client](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Azure-RMSDocs/blob/master/Azure-RMSDocs/rms-client/client-admin-guide-file-types.md) but nothing specific to MIP SDK.

For example, I am getting the following error when processing a Microsoft Publisher (.pub) file:

```
CRITICAL:msole_prop_read: assertion 'len < 0x10000' failed (`anonymous-namespace'::GsfLogHandler:src\file\common\gsf_utils.cpp:20
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/concept-supported-filetypes

Publisher files aren't supported for protection, only for labeling. Does that label attempt to apply protection?

Comment: No, the error occurs when calling engine.CreateFileHandlerAsync(stream, file.Name, false) even before touching the label.